# MVC Pass ViewBag to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, viewbag

I have a Viewbag that is a list that I am passing from the Controller to the View.
The Viewbag is a list of 10 records in my case. Once in the view, if the user clicks on save, I like to pass the content of the View to the [HttpPost] Create controller so that I can create records that are in the Viewbag. I am on sure how to do this. I have done the creation of a new record for 1 item but how do I do it for multiple records.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a quick example of using the ViewBag.  I would recommend switching and using a model to do your binding.  Here is a great article on it. [Model Binding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx)

Get Method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("Product1");
        items.Add("Product2");
        items.Add("Product3");

        ViewBag.Items = items;
        return View();
    }
```

Post Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
        //only selected prodcuts will be in the collection
        foreach (var product in collection)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
 {
     foreach (var p in ViewBag.Items)
     {
        <label for="@p">@p</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="@p" />
     }

    <div>
    <input id='btnSubmit' type="submit" value='submit' />
    </div>
 }
```